# How to include correlation among parameter vectors in the cost function?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, regularized

I have the following model:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim_in, lambda_=.3):
        super(FeatExtractorGR, self).__init__()

       '''The linear transform layer'''
        self.lt = nn.Linear(in_features = dim_in, out_features = 10, bias=True)
    
    '''The encoder'''
    self.feature_extractor = \
        nn.Sequential(
            #nn.Linear(in_features = 10, out_features = 30, bias=True),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(10),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features = 10, out_features = 20, bias=True),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(20),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features = 20, out_features = 10, bias=True),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(10),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

def forward(self, x):
    transformed = self.lt(x)
    return self.feature_extractor(transformed)
```

I want to force the weight vectors of the linear transformation layer to be uncorrelated. I tried to include the dot products among the vectors in the cost function:

```
        params=list(model.lt.parameters())[0]
        dotprod=torch.tensordot(params, params, dims=([1],[1])).abs().fill_diagonal_(0).sum()/2

        loss = other_losses + dotprod * weight
```

But this is not working, even with really high `weight`. The weight vectors from the `lt` layer are still highly correlated. I have also tried to remove `other_losses`, but no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, try removing `other_losses` and seeing if you can get it to work when you only care about correlation. This will better indicate where your problem is

Comment: Tried that, no effect.

Comment: I think there is an issue with your "correlation" formula. Covariance between random variables X and Y would be `Cov(X,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)` and your loss only takes the `E(XY)` term into account, doesn't it ? . Moreover, to make it a correlation you would have to divide by the deviations of X and Y (but I don't think that is important w.r.t the training though)

Comment: that is correct, I am approximating correlation with the dot product to reduce computational complexity. But this should also work IMO